# Only increment the lowest entry in postgres DB using Knex

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to get the row that has the lowest tallied column for a specific user, and then increment just that one column, and return it. This is what I wrote below, and I thought it would work, but it is incrementing every tally column for that user's options. And again, I just want the lowest tallied column ...

```
knex('options').where('user_id', user_id)
                        .orderBy('tally', 'asc')
                        .limit(1)
                        .first()
                        .increment('tally', 1)
                        .then((option) => {
                           console.log(option);
                           res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

Comment: You can check what kind of SQL is generated from your builder with `.toSQL()`. For example your query renders to something like: `update "options" set "tally" = "tally" + 1 where "user_id" = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with subquery:

```
knex('options')
  .increment('tally', 1)
  .whereIn('id', subQuery => {
    subQuery('options')
     .select('id')
     .where('user_id', user_id)
     .orderBy('tally', 'asc')
     .limit(1);
  })
  .then(option => {
    console.log(option);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That is what I was looking for.